# Array.includes always return false

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Object in the Arrays 0' th element as follows,

```
Array = {CreatedById: "Created By ID",CreatedDate: "Created Date",Id: 
"Record ID",IsDeleted: "Deleted",LastActivityDate: "Last Activity 
Date",LastModifiedById: "Last Modified By ID",LastModifiedDate: "Last 
Modified Date",Name: "Data Import Name",OwnerId: "Owner ID",SystemModstamp: 
"System Modstamp",Last_Name__c: "Last Name",Mandate_Date_Signed__c: "Mandate 
Date Signed",Mandate_End_Date__c: "Mandate End Date",Mandate__c: "Mandate"}
```

I'll need to check whether a key is available in the above array. I have used the `includes()` function like `Array.includes('Last Name')`. But it always return `false`. Did I miss anything? I'll need to check the key in the whole array even in key or value. Any modification to check the key in the `Object`?

Comment: `I have an array as follows,

Array = ` if you did that, then Array.includes will fail - you aren't overwriting the javascript `Array` object are you?

Comment: That is not an array. It is an object.

Comment: @JaromandaX even if he did, it would still fail.

Comment: Huh @PatrickRoberts? I said Array.includes **will fail** ... not return false ... but **will fail** - oh, you mean "even if he **didn't**" [overwrite Array] - yeah, I know that, because it's not an Array

Comment: @Jaromanda X. I debug the code. It returns false

Comment: @JaromandaX no, I meant exactly what I said because it sounded like you were implying that overwriting the JavaScript `Array` would cause a different outcome than failure.

Comment: @JaromandaX Actually overwriting the global `Array` wouldn't make `instance.includes(…)` fail, but of course this snippet is not creating an array instance.

Comment: `var obj = { your object }; ... obj.hasOwnProperty('whateveryouwanttolookfor')`

Comment: Also your object is not valid. Please fix your spacing, commas and quotes.

Comment: @Hariprasath - no, it doesn't ... what you have there is an OBJECT, an OBJECT does not have the `includes` method - ergo, your code will 1) wipe out the javascript `Array` object, and 2) fail with `Array.includes is not a function`

Comment: @Bergi I was referring directly to the code in the question :p

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I guess my English is inelegant - because I can't fathom how your statement relates to mine :D

Comment: Yes, It's an object and it has includes at the Array's 0' th element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain element, returning true or false as appropriate.

[Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own property names, in the same order as we get with a normal loop.

Since the object is not array, you can use `Object.keys()` to get an array of all the keys. The key you are trying to match is `Last_Name__c` not `Last Name`:

```js
var obj = {
CreatedById: "Created By ID",CreatedDate: "Created Date",Id: 
"Record ID",IsDeleted: "Deleted",LastActivityDate: "Last Activity Date",LastModifiedById: "Last Modified By ID",LastModifiedDate: "Last Modified Date",Name: "Data Import Name",OwnerId: "Owner ID",SystemModstamp: "System Modstamp",Last_Name__c: "Last Name",Mandate_Date_Signed__c: "Mandate Date Signed",Mandate_End_Date__c: "Mandate End Date",Mandate__c: "Mandate"};
var res = Object.keys(obj).includes('Last_Name__c');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

The method you're looking for is `hasOwnProperty`, which is a native method of the JS `Object` type. Like so:

```
let array = {
    CreatedById: "Created By ID",
    CreatedDate: "Created Date",
    Id: "Record ID",
    IsDeleted: "Deleted",
    LastActivityDate: "Last Activity Date",
    LastModifiedById: "Last Modified By ID",
    LastModifiedDate: "Last Modified Date",
    Name: "Data Import Name",
    OwnerId: "Owner ID",
    SystemModstamp: "System Modstamp",
    Last_Name__c: "Last Name",
    Mandate_Date_Signed__c: "Mandate Date Signed",
    Mandate_End_Date__c: "Mandate End Date",
    Mandate__c: "Mandate"
}

console.log(array.hasOwnProperty('CreatedById') ? 'True' : 'False'); // Outputs True
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty('OtherProperty') ? 'True' : 'False'); // Outputs False
```

Check out the documentation for the [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/hasOwnProperty) as well as the [JS Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) type.

Answer (score 0):

The fault I made is, I got a Map response from the back end and assign it to a List attribute in the front end that's why I got the response as an Object Array like in the question.

Now I have changed the front-end attribute type as Map and checked as follows,

```
if(Object.keys(Array).includes(KEY) || Object.values(Array).includes(key))
```

and it works according to the Mamun's Answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mainArray = [
{
 CreatedById: "Created By ID",
 CreatedDate: "Created Date",
 Id: "Record ID",
 IsDeleted: "Deleted",
 LastActivityDate: "Last Activity Date",
 LastModifiedById: "Last Modified By ID",
 LastModifiedDate: "Last Modified Date",
 Name: "Data Import Name",
 OwnerId: "Owner ID",
 SystemModstamp: "System Modstamp",
 Last_Name__c: "Last Name",
 Mandate_Date_Signed__c: "Mandate Date Signed",
 Mandate_End_Date__c: "Mandate End Date",
 Mandate__c: "Mandate"
}]


function find(array,searchKey,searchValue, match=false ){
    const findData = array.find(item=>!match ? item[searchKey] ===searchValue : item[searchKey].search(searchValue)>-1);

    return findData ? true : false

}

console.log('search exact `Data Import Name` => ',find(mainArray , 'Name', 'Data Import Name'));
console.log('search exact `Data` => ',find(mainArray , 'Name', 'Data'));
console.log('search contains `Data` => ', find(mainArray , 'Name', 'Data', true));
console.log('search contains `majid` => ', find(mainArray , 'Name', 'majid', true))




var obj = {
 CreatedById: "Created By ID",
 CreatedDate: "Created Date",
 Id: "Record ID",
 IsDeleted: "Deleted",
 LastActivityDate: "Last Activity Date",
 LastModifiedById: "Last Modified By ID",
 LastModifiedDate: "Last Modified Date",
 Name: "Data Import Name",
 OwnerId: "Owner ID",
 SystemModstamp: "System Modstamp",
 Last_Name__c: "Last Name",
 Mandate_Date_Signed__c: "Mandate Date Signed",
 Mandate_End_Date__c: "Mandate End Date",
 Mandate__c: "Mandate"
}
console.log(Reflect.get(obj ,'Name') ? true : false)
console.log(Reflect.get(obj ,'other') ? true : false)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a correct way.

```
JSON.stringify(obj).includes(key)
```